# Can't sort table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, html-table

I'm having trouble sorting a single-column table in Rails. Each row represents a single object (an article) and contains all of its attributes (`name`, `content`, `created_at`, `user`, etc.). The search function works fine (`Article.where`) but I can't seem to sort the table by any attributes, i.e. `Article.order('attribute')`. The default, which I can't change, is `created_at desc`. Am I overlooking something?

Here is my controller:

```
def index
   @title="Home"
   if params[:search]
      @search=params[:search]
      @articles=Article.where('name LIKE ? OR category LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%").paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page]) 
   else
      @articles=Article.order('name').paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
   end
end
```

And view:

```
<table> 
    <%= render @articles%>
</table>

<%= will_paginate @articles, :previous_label => "Prev", :next_label => "Next" %>
```

Comment: OT: You can use a named placeholder to make your `where` a bit nicer and LIKE isn't always case insensitive so you might want to downcase everything: `.where('lower(name) like :pat or lower(category) like :pat', :pat => "%#{params[:search].downcase}%")`.

Comment: Thanks..I will incorporate your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reorder` to override any default ordering.

`Article.reorder('name').paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])`

Comment: It worked! Oh man, cant believe I wasted so much time on a simple mistake. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I recommend my gem simple-search for these problems. It may be too simple, but worth a shot.

Comment: Can you describe *how* your gem would help? A short code sample would do wonders. Thanks!